# Unsupported SSL context options are set. The following options are present, but have been ignored: cafile

Tags: php, ssl, google-api-php-client, google-cloud-sql, google-php-sdk

Since earlier today (around 9:35AM EST), I'm getting this error message in the Google Cloud log:

```
  E 2015-07-09 10:35:51.967  200     779 B   889ms E 10:35:51.611 E 10:35:51.817 /get.php?u=xxxx@test.com&_=1436448941263
  190.188.222.26 - XXX [09/Jul/2015:06:35:51 -0700] "GET /get.php?u=xxxx@test.com&_=1436448941263 HTTP/1.1" 200 779 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.61 Safari/537.36" "mailroof-test.appspot.com" ms=889 cpu_ms=329 cpm_usd=0.000177 instance=00c61b117c0ffb0afc187ade6b0e941e8ff97f60 app_engine_release=1.9.24
  E 10:35:51.611 Unsupported SSL context options are set. The following options are present, but have been ignored: cafile
```

Still, the code seems to "work" in the sense that nothing is broken or missing in the functionality. But it is getting my log file full with this anoyment.

BTW, I was using PHP API 1.1.2 and today I upgraded to1.1.4 and later to the master version. I noticed the error log long after that and I thought that upgrade could be causing it. So I rolled back all the changes but still the error is there.

Any ideas of what could be causing this? and a solution?

PS: It seems to my like a ssl certificate error. Is it really possible?

Update: the error went away and now is back. The log is not being usefull since it doesn't indicate what is actually triggering the error. And it's making a lot of noise in the log. But the application is working... so, I'm just trying to figure it out what is wrong and where.

NOTE: I posted the same issue at github:

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/608

And more ppl seems to have simillar issues and none of us can detect what is causing it.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same question posted in the git repository, and today the developer confirmed a previous non official fix to the error:

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/608

Basically, the solution would be to comment line 91 of the Stream.php (in the IO folder), the online line that makes a reference to the 'cafile':

```
/* Dissabled by AR to prevent the SSL warning in the Log
  $requestSslContext["cafile"] = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacerts.pem';
*/
```

And it worked as promissed. So, if you encounter the same problem, that is the current solution.

Comment: Modifying an external dependency's files is not a good solution to propose.

Comment: I had this resolution from github. That's how I've been using it (so far, no problems). And I agree: it's not pretty but it works. Maybe in the upcomming API release they get that issue is addressed. But until then, this is the non-official patch.